# Problems with multiple Open IDs

Tags: support, linked-accounts

Few days back I registered my Facebook OpenId with stackoverflow.com; it worked fine until I spotted something (to be described in another post).

Today, I came to meta for reporting that, and I now see a new trouble at hand. I am using a new PC, which didn't have me logged into meta; therefore, I logged in using my Facebook account. Unfortunately, the system could not link this to my existing account. As I understand, stackexchange should use common authentication mechanism and I should have my accounts linked. Also, whenever I try to add the two IDs from here, I am getting the option to sign out; clearly I should get an option to link these two accounts.

Is this a general issue with Open ID, or is this fixable?

Comment: Just for your reference, this is my other Id: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151059/gunner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I see.

In this case you had a duplicate account on meta.so from 7 months ago that predates you adding that second openid on SO.

The new unmerged account *was correctly linked on the network*, however, we can't stop you from creating duplicate accounts in the past without a time machine...

Comment: Thanks. Hey, did you do some magic, they now appeared to be linked :)

Comment: He sprinkled some pixie dust :)